# Empty CSV file from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to ruby on rails and I am having trouble in exporting the data to csv. I have followed the following video:

https://medium.com/coderaga/rails-import-export-csv-data-without-gem-fbf2a36a84f6

I have put **require 'csv'** in application.rb file also.

My student.rb model has:

```
def self.to_csv(fields = column_names, options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv << fields
      all.each do |student|
        csv << student.attributes.values_at(*fields)
      end
    end
end
```

My students_controller has following:

```
    def index
    @students=Student.all
    puts @students
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv{send_data @students.to_csv(['UIN', 'Name' ,'Section', 'Attempts', 'Score'])}
    end
  end
```

I think the all.each statement is empty as when I am doing `puts student.attributes.values_at(*fields)`, there is nothing so that is why there is nothing being written. But I am not sure how can I fix it.

```
Student Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "students".* FROM "students"
#<Student:0x007f9a2386ddb8>
#<Student:0x007f9a2386dc78>
#<Student:0x007f9a2386db38>
  CACHE Student Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "students".* FROM "students"
```

Please help

Comment: is `Student::Import` a model?can you paste its content here?

Comment: No, its not a model.

Comment: if it's outside `/app` folder then you need to make sure it's loaded(check config files), I presume this file is in `/lib`?

Comment: which file? I have just dealt with controller and models, routes and appliction.rb files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
where.each do |student|
  puts student #Debug
  csv << student.attributes.values_at(*fields)
end
```

Comment: I tried following for debugging:
`all.each do |student|
            csv << student.attributes.values
            puts student.attributes.values_at(*fields)
          end`
so it is giving me no output but if I do `puts student.attributes.values` it is giving me the correct output. So, I think there is some problem with the *fields

Comment: I fixed it. I put the column name different earlier by mistake

Comment: @krishna if you could post your final solution, I can update my answer. Otherwise, feel free just to mark this as correct.